# "Aborted (core dumped)" error in dequeue method of queue class

Tags: c++, queue

This queue class's dequeue method doesn't work properly and I'm not sure why. When I run it it says "*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000018dfe50 ***", followed by a backtrace and then "Aborted (core dumped)".

At first I was deleting the bottom node directly, but I thought that might be the problem so I switched to deleting them another way.

Here's the dequeue method:

```
int Queue::dequeue() {
  if (isEmpty()) {
    cout << "ERROR: Can't dequeue from empty Queue"<< endl;
    return -1;
  } else {
    Node* n = top;
    if (n == NULL){
      bottom = top;
      return 0;
    }
    if (n->next == NULL){
      delete n;
      bottom = top;
      return 0;
    }
    while(n->next->next != NULL){
      n = n->next;
    }
    bottom = n;
    n = n->next;
    delete n;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And here's the whole file:

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  struct Node {
      int data;
      Node *next;
  };

  class Queue {
  public:
      Queue(); //constructor
      ~Queue(); //destructor
      void enqueue(int d); //enqueues node onto top of Queue
      int dequeue(); //dequeues bottom node off of Queue -- returns integer dequeued
      bool isEmpty(); //checks if Queue is empty
      void print(); //print contents of Queue from top to bottom

  private:
      Node* top; //points to top node in Queue
      Node* bottom; //points to bottom node in Queue
  };

  Queue::Queue() {
      top = NULL;
      bottom = NULL;
  }

  Queue::~Queue() {
    while (!isEmpty())
      dequeue();
  }

  void Queue::enqueue(int d) {
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = d;

    temp->next = top;
    top = temp;

    if (temp->next == NULL){
      delete bottom;
      bottom = temp;
    }
  }

  int Queue::dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      cout << "ERROR: Can't dequeue from empty Queue"<< endl;
      return -1; //error
    } else {
      Node* n = top;
      if (n == NULL){
        bottom = top;
        return 0;
      }
      if (n->next == NULL){
        delete n;
        bottom = top;
        return 0;
      }
      while(n->next->next != NULL){
        n = n->next;
      }
      bottom = n;
      n = n->next;
      delete n;
      return 0;
    }
  }

  bool Queue::isEmpty() {
    return (top==NULL);
  }

  //Print Queue from top to bottom
  void Queue::print(){
    Node* n = top;
    while(n != NULL){
      cout << n->data << endl;
      n = n->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  int main(){
      Queue* s = new Queue();
      s->print();
      s->enqueue(20);
      s->enqueue(30);
      s->print();
      s->enqueue(40);
      s->enqueue(12);
      s->print();
      s->dequeue();
      s->print();
      s->dequeue();
      s->print();
      s->dequeue();
      delete s;

      return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you delete a node, you need to update all the pointers that point to the node being deleted.  You need to do this in two places.

First, in the `n->next == NULL` case, the `Queue` only has one node.  After you call `delete n`, `top` still points to this now deleted node, and you need to update `top` (to NULL or `nullptr`) before changing the value of `bottom`.

In the last case, where there is more than one node in the list, you delete the last node but the `next` pointer of the previous node still points to it.  After the `n = n->next` expression, you need to set `bottom->next` to point to the node that `n->next` now points to (which, since `n` is the last node in the `Queue`, is NULL).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm having a hard time grasping pointers but this answer has really helped in my understanding.